# Why logrotate maxsize condition is not working?

Tags: logrotate

I've specific problem with logrotate which is rotating before reaches the limit - set by maxsize

```
logrotate version - 3.8.6
```

I've a custom logrotate file

```
/var/web/log/access_log
{
    rotate 40
    maxsize 200M
    missingok
    compress
}
```

and logrotate is set in crontab without -f and rotate logs almost every hour despite it did not reach the maxsize listed below (logs are rotated with few MBs):

```
 95642 Sep  8 08:29 access_log.2020-09-08_08.gz
 86705 Sep  8 09:29 access_log.2020-09-08_09.gz
 70344 Sep  8 09:59 access_log.2020-09-08_10.gz
 86491 Sep  8 10:59 access_log.2020-09-08_11.gz
117124 Sep  8 11:59 access_log.2020-09-08_12.gz
106386 Sep  8 12:59 access_log.2020-09-08_13.gz
113683 Sep  8 13:59 access_log.2020-09-08_14.gz
104494 Sep  8 15:29 access_log.2020-09-08_15.gz
 99380 Sep  8 17:00 access_log.2020-09-08_17.gz
 87250 Sep  8 19:30 access_log.2020-09-08_19.gz
```

Now:

```
8632827 Sep  9 12:56 access_log
```

The output:

```
empty log files are rotated, log files >= 209715200 are rotated earlier, old logs are removed
considering log /var/web/log/access_log
  log needs rotating

... Sep  9 13:00 access_log.2020-09-09_13.gz
```

Can sb tell me what is wrong? Why are logs rotated before size limit?
Thanks

Comment: did you reload logrotate or cron service?

Comment: Of course, before I started mess up with max size I had one log per day (daily rotation...) Now as you can see, logs are rotated more frequently, which confirms logrotate reload... Also I've updated cron service to commit every 30 minutes

Comment: Deb/Ubuntu *do* have a `maxsize`, so the accepted answer is wrong. Your problem is caused by an interaction of the settings of the `cron` period, and  whatever you specified as the rotate period in your config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the logrotate manual page there is no "maxsize" option, just "size" and "minsize".

[image]

[image]

From https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

If you change "maxsize" to "size" I'm sure it will work!

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
I was looking at wrong manual ...https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html